# Airflow scheduler not scheduling simple DAG task immediately

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have scheduled a DAG with a simple bash task to run every 5th minute:

```
# bash_dag.py

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date' : datetime(2019, 5, 30)
}

dag = DAG(
    'bash_count',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
    catchup = False
)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag
)
```

Scheduling works fine, DAG is executing every 5th minute threshold. However, I have noticed that there is a significant delay between the 5th minute threshold and task queueing time. For the examples shown in the image, task queueing takes in between 3 to 50 seconds. For example, last DAG execution in the image was supposed to be triggered after 20:05:00 but  task instance was queued 28 seconds later (20:05:28).

I'm surprised this is the case, since the DAG being scheduled has a single very simple task. Is this a normal airflow delay? Should I expect further delays when dealing with more complex DAGs?

I'm running a local airflow server with Postgres as db on a 16 GB Mac with OS Mojave. Machine is not resource constrained.

[image: task queueing delay]